# В чем причина появления этого сообщения?

Tags: php, apache, apache2.4

Вот такое сообщение появляется на экране, в чем причина не пойму:
`You don't have permission to access /.html on this server.
Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) Server at marmilon.com Port 80`

Comment: У вас так и называется директория? .html? Именно с точкой? Может в конфигурации опечатка, проверьте

Comment: Прикрепите пожалуйста файлы конфигурации, настроек виртуального хоста и error log от апача, попробую разобраться, иначе это просто гадание будет

Comment: Сложно было в переводчик вставить и посмотреть, что пишут? А пишут там, о том, что у вас нет доступа до `/.html`, Возможно с правами, что - то.